# Cannot clone from Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

I am using Bitbucket for the first time and I signed with with my Gmail account so I did not provide password. But when I try to clone a project, it's asking me for my password and I tried my gmail password but it fails obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitBucket doesn't know your Gmail password. It definitely should not. Go to https://id.atlassian.com/ and set the password for your account.